# STR function not working

Tags: python, string

I am extremely new to programming. I have the problem below, where I am trying to list the name of the person with a number next to him. So here, I am trying to join "steve" to "100". I want the outcome to be steve100. The training video says you can't concatenate strings and int's, so you have to type str(grades[1]) to get the 100 to concatenate to steve. However, it doesn't work for me, see below.

```
>>> grades = ["steve", 100, "john", 50]
>>> grades[0] + grades[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
>>> grades[0] + str(grades[1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>>
```

Comment: As it stands, `grades[0] + str(grades[1])` should work. What has probably happened is that you have assigned something to the name `str` somewhere. Try `del str` and then run the command again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to parse the int to string, and you are doing it correctly with the `str` function:

```
grades[0]+str(grades[1])
```

You are getting the error `str object is not callable` probably because you have defined a `str` variable before.

You can run `del str` then try again, it will work =)

Comment: Ok I will test it. This makes me wonder though, why does Python allow me to assign the name of a function to another variable? It seems strange to let me do that (assuming str is actally a function).

Comment: Python does allow naming (redefining) variables or functions with the exact same name as some built-in functions, which prevents the original function from being usable.

Comment: As to why this is allowed, Python is an open language and doesn't limit you very much in many aspects, including the names you can use. That does lead to some beginner bugs, but in general, if you know what you are doing, it is nice to have that kind of freedom. Of course, it is expected of the programmer to be responsible and understand what he is writing =)